# how to add a coroutine to a running asyncio loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

How can one add a new coroutine to a running asyncio loop? Ie. one that is already executing a set of coroutines.

I guess as a workaround one could wait for existing coroutines to complete and then initialize a new loop (with the additional coroutine). But is there a better way?

Comment: Actually `asyncio.create_task` throws a runtime error **if there is no loop running**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_task) for scheduling new coroutines:

```
import asyncio

async def cor1():
    ...

async def cor2():
    ...

async def main(loop):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    t1 = loop.create_task(cor1())
    await cor2()
    await t1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
loop.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but as far as I understand, this answer is mistaken. Here the first invocation of `main` creates the coroutine and the loop starts after that. In other words, this example schedules the coroutines before the loop has started. Which is not what I asked for.

Comment: `main` is simply there as a wrapper; I just wanted to point out `loop.create_task`'s usage. `create_task` does exactly what you want. -- I've edited the example to make it clear that `main` would block before running `create_task`.

Comment: you cannot call `loop.run_until_complete()` while the loop is running

Comment: How could this possibly be the answer? the task is created before loop start. How to add a task to a running loop means an event loop is started and then we want a task to be added to the loop

Comment: The line `t1 = loop.create_task(cor1())` creates **and schedule** the task in the event loop, ready to be executed as soon as the current corroutine (in this case `main`) switch out with for example `await asyncio.sleep(0)`

Comment: [In Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) `asyncio.get_event_loop()` raises a deprecation warning if there is no current event loop.

Answer (score 44):

To add a function to an already running event loop you can use:

`asyncio.ensure_future(my_coro())`

In my case I was using multithreading (`threading`) alongside `asyncio` and wanted to add a task to the event loop that was already running. For anyone else in the same situation, be sure to explicitly state the event loop (as one doesn't exist inside a `Thread`). i.e:

In global scope:

```
event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

Then later, inside your `Thread`:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(my_coro(), loop=event_loop)
```

Comment: To add a task to a loop running in different thread (say main thread) one need to use:
`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)` instead.


See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe

Comment: This is correct in Python before 3.7. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks  "create_task() has been added in Python 3.7. Prior to Python 3.7, the low-level asyncio.ensure_future() function can be used instead".

Answer (score 18):

If the task is to add a coroutine(s) to a loop that is already executing some coroutines, then you can use this solution of mine

```
import asyncio
import time
from threading import Thread

from random import randint


# first, we need a loop running in a parallel Thread
class AsyncLoopThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    def run(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        self.loop.run_forever()


# example coroutine
async def coroutine(num, sec):
    await asyncio.sleep(sec)
    print(f'Coro {num} has finished')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # init a loop in another Thread
    loop_handler = AsyncLoopThread()
    loop_handler.start()

    # adding first 5 coros
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'Add Coro {i} to the loop')
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coroutine(i, randint(3, 5)), loop_handler.loop)

    time.sleep(3)
    print('Adding 5 more coros')

    # adding 5 more coros
    for i in range(5, 10):
        print(f'Add Coro {i} to the loop')
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coroutine(i, randint(3, 5)), loop_handler.loop)

    # let them all finish
    time.sleep(60)
```

After execution of this example we will get this output:

```
Add Coro 0 to the loop
Add Coro 1 to the loop
Add Coro 2 to the loop
Add Coro 3 to the loop
Add Coro 4 to the loop
Coro 0 has finished
Adding 5 more coros
Add Coro 5 to the loop
Add Coro 6 to the loop
Add Coro 7 to the loop
Add Coro 8 to the loop
Add Coro 9 to the loop
Coro 1 has finished
Coro 3 has finished
Coro 2 has finished
Coro 4 has finished
Coro 9 has finished
Coro 5 has finished
Coro 7 has finished
Coro 6 has finished
Coro 8 has finished

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: no needs "return self.loop" in "def run(self)"

Comment: @mug896 you're right indeed. thanks for noticing

Comment: Thanks man, this is super helpful when dealing with GUI frameworks, so it does not block the main thread.

Answer (score 16):

None of the answers here seem to exactly answer the question. It is possible to add tasks to a running event loop by having a "parent" task do it for you. I'm not sure what the most pythonic way to make sure that parent doesn't end until it's children have all finished (assuming that's the behavior you want), but this does work.

```
import asyncio
import random


async def add_event(n):
    print('starting ' + str(n))
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    print('ending ' + str(n))
    return n


async def main(loop):

    added_tasks = []

    delays = list(range(5))

    # shuffle to simulate unknown run times
    random.shuffle(delays)

    for n in delays:
        print('adding ' + str(n))
        task = loop.create_task(add_event(n))
        added_tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

    print('done adding tasks')

    results = await asyncio.gather(*added_tasks)
    print('done running tasks')

    return results


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results = loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
print(results)
```

Answer (score 14):

Your question is very close to "How to add function call to running program?"

When exactly you need to add new coroutine to event loop?

Let's see some examples. Here program that starts event loop with two coroutines parallely:

```
import asyncio
from random import randint


async def coro1():
    res = randint(0,3)
    await asyncio.sleep(res)
    print('coro1 finished with output {}'.format(res))
    return res

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        coro1(),
        coro1()
    ) # here we have two coroutines running parallely

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
coro1 finished with output 1
coro1 finished with output 2
[Finished in 2.2s]
```

May be you need to add some coroutines that would take results of `coro1` and use it as soon as it's ready? In that case just create coroutine that await `coro1` and use it's returning value:

```
import asyncio
from random import randint


async def coro1():
    res = randint(0,3)
    await asyncio.sleep(res)
    print('coro1 finished with output {}'.format(res))
    return res

async def coro2():
    res = await coro1()
    res = res * res
    await asyncio.sleep(res)
    print('coro2 finished with output {}'.format(res))
    return res

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        coro2(),
        coro2()
    ) # here we have two coroutines running parallely

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
coro1 finished with output 1
coro2 finished with output 1
coro1 finished with output 3
coro2 finished with output 9
[Finished in 12.2s]
```

Think about coroutines as about regular functions with specific syntax. You can start some set of functions to execute parallely (by `asyncio.gather`), you can start next function after first done, you can create new functions that call others.

Comment: Coroutines run *concurrently*, not *in parallel*. Not quite the same thing.

Comment: "create coroutine that await coro1". Heck, I was trying complicated things to fire a request based on a prior request. Thanks so much for this!