# Asyncio among multiple classes

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm fairly new to asyncio, and I'm not sure what is the best approach to what I'm trying to achieve.

I have several classes, one of which will instantiate instances of the others. It will also be running a loop of listening to messages, and calling methods of other classes when it receives certain messages.

The issue is these classes also need to run loops. Currently, I have this in my main class, as the last thing in the `__init__` def:

```
    ...
    self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start_services())
```

`self.start_services()` will then go on to do some things, wait for a message to be sent to start services (which all works fine), then attempts to instantiate the other classes:

```
    # load TPE services
    self.logger.log(f'Loading services for TPEs: {trading_pair_exchanges}...')
    for tpe in trading_pair_exchanges:
        TradingPairExchangeDataService.TradingPairExchangeDataService(tpe, ['EMA26'])

    # load realtime service
    self.logger.log('Loading RealtimeService...')
    RealTimeDataService.RealTimeDataService(trading_pair_exchanges, ['EMA26'])
```

Now the problem. As standalone tests, these classes would start their async functions like this (this would be at the end of the `__init__` def:

```
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(self.retrieve_real_time_data())
```

This doesn't work, I've looked at a few articles but couldn't find a solution, although I now know that this is like starting a job scheduler inside a job scheduler.

I've tried awaiting, calling a non-async function that would then await `self.retrieve_real_time_data()`, but nothing has worked so far.

What can I do to easily add an async method to a running loop, **from inside the loop while it's running, and from an `__init__`?**

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34499904/3920623) is the right answer you're looking for.

Comment: thank you that seems to work